# How can I close db connection from spark.read?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I can select data from database in Spark like this:

```
var df = spark.read.
format("jdbc").
option("url", "jdbc:db://<DB server>:<DB port>/<dbname>").
option("user", "<username>").
option("password", "<password>").
option("dbtable", "<your table>").
load()
```

But after this how can I close db connection? Is it closed automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark opens and closes the JDBC connections as needed, to extract/validate metadata when building query execution plan, to save dataframe partitions to a database, or to compute dataframe when scan is triggered by a Spark action. See [`JdbcRelationProvider`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.2/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JdbcRelationProvider.scala#L49),[`JdbcUtils`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.2/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JdbcUtils.scala#L653), and
[`JDBCRDD`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.2/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JDBCRDD.scala#L281) source for where/how exactly its done.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, Spark is a distributed system. Each executor will require its own connection(s) to the database (e.g. when doing partitioned reads). There's simply no way how you could close all opened connections manually.

All of this is taken care of automatically by Spark and nothing you have to worry about..

Comment: spark.read , it reads data from driver or all executors?

Comment: The actual work in Spark is always happening on an executor. By default only one executor is used to read all data into one partition. To parallelise that you have to tell Spark how to partition your query into multiple ones setting numPartitions, partitionColumn, lowerBound, upperBound. Check out the details here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

Comment: so yes, its just on one executor ,  But i cant close that connection manually , right?

Comment: exactly, that connection is not exposed anywhere (and it's typically happening remotely)